# Automatically export submissions as PDF to a directory on the server, or external location

Tags: 8, webforms

**Background**
Drupal 8 have a great new feature: Ability to use entity_print to export submissions as pdf, and even to attach the pdf to email and send.

**Request**
Because of the sensitivity of some information, sending them by email is not an acceptable option.
Is it possible, to instead automatically generate the PDF when a submission is created or updated, and save it in a directory on the server or another external location?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Sorry you got downvoted. But unfortunately your question is way too broad. Please update your question to include your previous attempts; to share a detailed and narrowly-scoped problem and where exactly you are stuck right now. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a drush command that will export all PDF documents in the tar file.

```
drush webform-export --exporter='webform_entity_print:pdf' contact >  contact.tar.gz
```

Otherwise, you would have to write custom code to generate the PDF documents when a submission is created. You can use `WebformEntityPrintWebformExporter::writeSubmission` as starting point for generating a submission's PDF document.

BTW, I do not recommend generating the PDF when a submission is created because it would slow down your site. Instead, I would [queue](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-queue-api-powerful-manual-and-cron-queueing/) the PDF generating.

Comment: Hi; Thanks for your advice on this request. After analysis, the solution that will work for my case will be to generate a pdf file after each form submission. I've followed your tutorial on webform entity print and ended up with a pdf field that is attached to my form. From that I can get the pdf version of the form without problem. Then I've created a handler I will like to use to auto export the pdf. This is where I'm stocked.

Comment: I'm using the public postSave function, and trying to use $webform_submission->getData() to get the value of the the ['pdf'] array, and use system_retrieve_file() to get the file and save it to my location. 2 issues: the get->Data() is not getting the pdf value; and when I trick the system and use and existing pdf, the files is copied to the location, but is corrupted. I think WebformEntityPrintWebformExporter::writeSubmission as you sugested will work, but don't know how to use this...

Comment: PDF generation has access controls to protect user data and if you try to call the generated PDF via system_retrieve_file() you will get an access denied page.  You need to extract the code which writes the PDF from WebformEntityPrintWebformExporter::writeSubmission.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know that's the way to go. Can you please help me with and example of achieving this? my current standing. I've already setup webform and webformentityprint, and attached a pdf field to generate the pdf. I'm using the postSave function in my handler. Can you show me how in my postSave function I can use WebformEntityPrintWebformExporter::writeSubmission and save the generate form somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use this snippet as starting point, https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print/issues/2843869#comment-11920433